# Add a less than or equal to symbol to R string

Tags: r, symbols

```
x <- 'Age <= 70yrs'
```

I would like the output to actually show the less than or equal symbol. Is that possible? The output will be used as a column name in a matrix. Thanks!

Comment: Try  "Age \u2264 70yrs"

Comment: Is the two character version of “less than or equal” acceptable or are you asking for the single glyph version?

Comment: single glyph version. Mael's answer worked - thanks!